# JUnit tests unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, junit

I have several JUnit tests that I running to test a message parsing system.

Running the tests individually with the 3s timeout is ok - they all pass.

Running the tests all at once causes problems and I frequently see the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected <3> but collection size <0>
```

I can get around this by increasing the timeout to something like 30s, but in this case, I find that Test1 is rerun for some reason. This is what I see in the logs when running Test6 for example and increasing the timeout on `runforMilliseconds(3000, () -> messageProcessor.start());` to `runforMilliseconds(30000, () -> messageProcessor.start());`... as a result this a lot of assertion errors:

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] Started parsing Test1
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6] Started parsing Test6
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] Started parsing Test2
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5] Started parsing Test5
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] Started parsing Test3
```

This is an example of a unit test:

Test1.java

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    test1Mapper.deleteAll();
    messageTestMapper.deleteAll();
    setupMessages();
}

@Test
public void Test1() throws Exception {
    messageTestMapper.insertOne(new TestMessage(message1)):
    messageTestMapper.insertOne(new TestMessage(message2)):
    messageTestMapper.insertOne(new TestMessage(message3)):

    runforMilliseconds(3000, () -> messageProcessor.start());
    List<TestMessageDetails) actualTestMessageDetails = test1Mapper.select();
    assertThat(actualTestMessageDetails, hasSize(3));
}

@SneakyThrows
private void runforMilliseconds(int n, Runnable runnable) throws Exception {
    try {
        CompleteableFuture.runAsync(runnable).get(n, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        log.info("End running");
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your test shows that your implementation has a problem, so fix it!

Comment: How do you run these junit tests in parallel? Also, please add the full source code of your test class and the output you get when running the unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of your unit tests using the same `test1Mapper` and `messageTestMapper` variables? If so, consider giving each test its own individual mapper variables so that you can run them in parallel without one test affecting the outcome of the others.

Comment: Each test has its own mapper e.g. `test1Mapper`, `test2Mapper`, etc. `messageTestMapper` is an interface that inserts rows into an memory database. Prior to each test running, it is cleared but for some reason the tests (although running in parallel) - appear to be rerunning when the timeout period is extended.